# Clearing an ObserveableArray located in a separate viewmodel

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, single-page-application

I need to clear the contents of an observableArray that is located in one viewmodel while the user is in another viewmodel.  Can that be done?

For example, lets say I have an observeableArray called `myArray`. `myArray` is located in `TestPage1.js`.  The user does something to populate that observeableArray while on TestPage1 and then navigates to `TestPage2.js`. I need a way to clear the contents of `myArray` FROM TestPage2 so that when a user returns to TestPage1, no data bound to `myArray` is displayed.

Clearing the contents before leaving TestPage1 is not an option since the decision to clear or the contents of `myArray` is really based on what the user does.

Answer (score 0):

I would use event aggregation. I have made one for SignalR, if you have no use for SignalR in your project you can use this one that has the server side functionally striped

http://jsfiddle.net/AV39k/

You subscribe to a event like

```
 MyApp.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyApp.DeleteCustomerMessage, this.customerDeleted, this);
```

The complete framework can be found here
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy